# What Latin phrase did Descartes use to denote his Cartesian demon

Tags: descartes

I'm referring to the "evil demon", "malicious demon", "evil genius", etc, depending on translation. I'm looking for the original latin phrase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From meditation 1:

> , sed genium aliquem malignum eundemque summe potentem et callidum omnem suam industriam in eo posuisse, ut me falleret: (http://www.gutenberg.org/files/23306/23306-h/23306-h.htm)

genium malignum --> evil genius

or possibly genius malignus

depending on how he's doing his declining of Latin.

In translation:

> but some evil genius not less powerful than deceitful,
>   has employed his whole energies in deceiving me (http://selfpace.uconn.edu/class/percep/DescartesMeditations.pdf)

Comment: True, but OP does ask for the Latin phrase. If he can't decipher Latin well enough to find the phrase there ...

Comment: … didn’t Descartes also use *deus deceptor* somewhere?

Comment: If so not in the meditations

Comment: Corpus Descartes allows online search for in all his writings.  Genius/m/, deceptor, etc  produces some dozens of results, so you can make have an answer as to where http://www.unicaen.fr/puc/sources/prodescartes/index.php?action=module&module=search&cmd=query